# Omega 4 php warnings with node_modules folder with gulp install

Tags: theming

So, I have been happily using Omega 4 with SASS for a while. For workflow and performance reasons, I went with a Gulp/Ruby SASS set up. Recently, I've had a bunch of warnings pop up related to errors in the file.inc file in the includes folder. At this stage, I don't really know what's causing the errors. I sometimes get them at top of the page above my content (where sass warnings usually go) as well as in the pink/orange php warnings block. This seems to happen when it's not happy with something in my sass formatting, but again I'm not sure.

Any insight into what is causing this would be appreciated.

```
Warning: opendir(sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie,sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in file_scan_directory() (line 2118 of C:\Users\Nick\Sites\devdesktop\postcatlocal\includes\file.inc).
Warning: opendir(sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in file_scan_directory() (line 2118 of C:\Users\Nick\Sites\devdesktop\postcatlocal\includes\file.inc).
Warning: opendir(sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie,sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in file_scan_directory() (line 2118 of C:\Users\Nick\Sites\devdesktop\postcatlocal\includes\file.inc).
Warning: opendir(sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in file_scan_directory() (line 2118 of C:\Users\Nick\Sites\devdesktop\postcatlocal\includes\file.inc).
Warning: opendir(sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie,sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in file_scan_directory() (line 2118 of C:\Users\Nick\Sites\devdesktop\postcatlocal\includes\file.inc).
Warning: opendir(sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in file_scan_directory() (line 2118 of C:\Users\Nick\Sites\devdesktop\postcatlocal\includes\file.inc).
Warning: opendir(sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie,sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in file_scan_directory() (line 2118 of C:\Users\Nick\Sites\devdesktop\postcatlocal\includes\file.inc).
Warning: opendir(sites/all/themes/postomega/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/dateformat/node_modules/meow/node_modules/read-pkg-up/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/load-json-file/node_modules/pinkie-promise/node_modules/pinkie): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in file_scan_directory() (line 2118 of C:\Users\Nick\Sites\devdesktop\postcatlocal\includes\file.inc).
```

Comment: This might be related to: https://www.drupal.org/node/2329453

Comment: seems like it, I'll dig around for one of the patches. Thanks!

Comment: ok, I wrote an article about this as well: http://dannyenglander.com/blog/drupal-drush-segmentation-fault-11-error-avoiding-rabbit-hole but might not be exactly what you are running in to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're using Windows, there has been a [long term issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3697) with NPM in which the nesting structure of node_module dependencies breaks windows.  The issue is that the folders nest so far that they create a file path longer than windows can accommodate.

For a long time it appeared that they did not want to correct this, and there were various ways to get around it that didn't always work, but it seems that they have finally added an option in [NPM3](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0) that allows you to flatten dependencies.

If you upgrade to [NPM3](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0), delete your `node_modules` folder and rerun `npm install` you shouldn't have this issue any more.